# Splitting XSD scheme into several files

Tags: xml, xsd, xerces

I try to build a following set of XSD schemes for computers game's map data :

1. CreatureDefinitionsSchema.xsd
2. CreatureSchema.xsd
3. GoalList.xsd
4. LightScheme.xsd
5. RoomScheme.xsd
6. SeatScheme.xsd
7. TrapScheme.xsd

The central is  MapDefinitionSchema.xsd  schema, which ought to reference other schemas.
I havent' come across such example but general idea is to create complementary set

1. CreatureDefinitionsSchema.xml
2. CreatureSchema.xml
3. GoalList.xml
4. LightScheme.xml
5. RoomScheme.xml
6. SeatScheme.xml
7. TrapScheme.xml

And use it in MapDefinition.xml with xsd:import .
What I want is to be able to validate MapDefinition.xml against MapDefinitionScheme.xsd
and other xml files against their *.xsd counterparts.

However I see I manage to xs:import types from other xsd (not what I want)  . What I want is more like :

```
<xs:element name="GameMap">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MapSizeX">  </xs:element >
            <xs:element name="MapSizeY">  </xs:element >                
            <xs:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="SeatScheme.xsd" />
        </xs:sequence>           

    </xs:complexType>
```

, but I get

> > Engine name: Xerces
> >     Severity: error
> >     Description: s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'sequence' must match (annotation?, (element | group | choice | sequence | any)*). A problem was found starting at: include.
> >     Start location: 9:18
> >     End location: 9:28 <<

Seems I cannot put include those elements at random.

> My SeatScheme.xsd :
>
> ```
> <xs:element name="SeatList" type="Seat"/>        
>     <xs:complexType name="Seat">
>     <xs:sequence>
>         <xs:element name="color" type="xs:string"/>
>         <xs:element name="faction" type="xs:string"/>
>         <xs:element name="startingX" type="xs:integer"/>
>         <xs:element name="startingY" type="xs:integer"/>
>         <xs:element name="colorR" type="xs:decimal"/>            
>         <xs:element name="colorG" type="xs:decimal"/>
>         <xs:element name="colorB" type="xs:decimal"/>            
>     </xs:sequence>
> </xs:complexType> </xs:schema>
> ```

Is that ever doable , not operating on types but on elements  ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing XInclude, which does textual inclusion (well, tree-grafting) of the referenced file at an arbitrary location, and XSD's include and import declarations, which can only operate at the top level (that is, as children of the xs:schema element). You have declared the XInclude namespace within an xs:include element, which is pretty confusing.

You can use XInclude to build a schema document just as you can use it to build any other XML document, but it's not the usual approach. The usual approach is to use xs:include (if the definitions are in the same namespace) or xs:import (if they are in a different namespace). If you want to include something in the middle of the structure, the way to do it is (a) at the top level, include a schema document that defines a named model group (xs:group name="n"), and (b) at the point you want to include that group, include it with a model group reference: `<xs:group ref="n"/>`

Comment: That's half of it !, basicly I wanted to have each <xs:element> defined in separate xsd file so I can validate XML's against it later ( containning only some parts of game Data ! ) . <xs:group > cannot contain elements (annotation?, (all | choice | sequence))

Comment: Ahh I did not notice I can wrap element in one of those aforementioned containers and than into group ... :)